# Can I embed an excel file in a sharepoint page so it can be used, but not downloaded?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, excel

I have an instructor who teaches excel, and wishes to administer an exam, but doesn't want the students to be able to download the file. 
Is there a quick way to embed the excel document into a SharePoint page and remove the ability to click a button to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download ability inherits from user permission on this Excel file.

You can remove the download permission of this file from the students in the document library by setting **unique permission** for the file, for example, View Only.

[image]

[image]

Then you can add the Excel file to a site page using [File Viewer web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-file-viewer-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c).

It will not hide the download button on the File Viewer web part, but it will give an error message when someone with View Only permission click on it.

[image]

Reference:
[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate your input. My challenge is that giving them view only permissions denies them the ability to work with the file in order to complete their exam. I'm trying to find a way to allow them to complete the exam, but not download the file. (Work with it in the browser only.)

Comment: @AnotherUnique I’m afraid that is not possible. We cannot prevent users from opening Excel file using client application while allowing them to edit this file.